# Git diff without clone

Tags: git, git-diff

We recently migrated from SVN to Git, and I'm trying to convert our deployment scripts to pull from the new repo.

One script creates a "hotfix", which just includes files that have changed between two selected tags using SVN diff. However, git diff will only work inside a cloned repository (unlike git archive). We don't have the need or disk space for a working copy of the repository on the deployment machine.

Is there any way to get git diff to work without the local repo, or to simulate its output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you are actually worried about the working copy and not the repo, just clone with `--bare`. That will clone the repo without a working copy. You other option is to run `git diff` on the server and send the output to the client.

But it sounds like you are doing something that git might be able to do for you. Why are you creating those hotfixes?

Comment: It is a PHP application. We pull the changed files from source control, encode them with ioncube, then transfer them to customers' servers.